# What is the best way to implement this data structure in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I need some help with implementing a data structure for my code. The code looks through folders and extracts data from specific files within. The folder name gives me a unique serial number and a date. There could be multiple dates for the same serial. The files give me the name of the variable and the data. Not all serial and date combinations will contain the same variable names hence they need to be added at the point of loading the file.
My initial thought was to have a dictionary of dictionaries like `{Serial: {Date: {file: data}}` but while updating a serial with another date the original is overwritten. I understand this is usual behavior but not i what i need. If i try and populate the structure using `aDict[Serial][Date]...` i get a key error (im not able to key index further than one []). Any ideas?

edit1: Some additional info: the folder titles have the standard XXXXXX_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS where XXXXXX is the serial. inside there are a variety of files with the same suffix/file format. For example folder 111111_20220524_135000 could contain files a.cvs, b.csv, c.csv while 111111_20220524_135500 could contain  b.csv, c.csv, d.cvs. Im trying to collate all of the data from different days/times, referencing to the serial number. I cant prepopulate any fields; i dont know how many dates there could be for each serial, or the variety of files for each date

Thanks

Comment: "There could be multiple dates for the same serial" - in this case, your dictionary should have the `Serial` as the key and **a list of `Date`s as the value**: `{Serial: [{Date01: {file: data}}, {Date02: {file: data}}, ...]}`.

Comment: You have not said what you are trying to accomplish.   Your starting with what you think you need as the request.   I would suggest a bit more info in what your trying to wind up with given the initial state (folder structure, etc).

Comment: Ive added some more detail. jfaccioni how can dat01, date02 etc be added on the fly?

Comment: @Nanchild initialize the value as an empty list, then use its append method.

Comment: @jfaccioni i loose the ability to access the data with key though as the array will be indexed through 0,1,2...